# What is the simplest and the fastest way to make manual for the iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, manual

I have developed some app and want to add some manual for it. I mean, that there is button "Info" in the main menu of the app, so pushing this button, will appear that manual with text and images. I just need advice for the optimal solution, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using a `UIWebView` for this. It allows the simplest way to customize the view fully in terms of fonts, images, layout, etc. Just write an html file, add it to the project, and set it as the page for the `UIWebView`.